# Connect MacBook Pro to Two Monitors

Tags: display, hdmi

I'm trying to connect my M1 (2020) MacBook Pro to two external monitors. I know it can
't natively do this, so I bought HyperDrive's 10 in 1 connector that has two HDMI ports. It's able to extend the display to two monitors, however I want to rotate the monitors differently (main one horizontal, second one vertical). Is this possible? My main monitor is a Dell U2414H and my secondary is a Republic of Gamers Pg258Q. Thanks.